# How to build the following region?

Tags: regions, syntax, geometry, discretization

Consider a 3D figure defined by the dependence $\Delta x(z),\Delta y(z)$. One example is a pyramidal frustum, for which $\Delta x, \Delta y$ are linear functions of $z$, and $z$ lies inside the interval
$$
z_{\text{min}}<z<z_{\text{max}} < z_{\text{vertex}},
$$ where $z_{\text{vertex}}$ is the value of $z$ at which $\Delta x=\Delta y = 0$. The corresponding region (`reg`) may be obtained in Mathematica as an intersection of the pyramid (`pyramid`) and the cuboid (`cuboid`) with the transverse dimensions equal to the maximal $\Delta x, \Delta y$:

```
Dxin = 3;
Dxout = 1;
xcenter = 5;
Dyin = 6;
Dyout = 2;
ycenter = 0;
zmin = 450;
zmax = 460;
Dxz[z_] = 
  Dxin (zmax - z)/(zmax - zmin) + Dxout*(z - zmin)/(zmax - zmin);
Dyz[z_] = 
  Dyin (zmax - z)/(zmax - zmin) + Dyout*(z - zmin)/(zmax - zmin);
zvertex = z /. Solve[Dxz[z] == 0., z][[1]];
pyramid = 
  Pyramid[{{xcenter - Dxin/2, ycenter - Dyin/2, 
     zmin}, {xcenter - Dxin/2, ycenter + Dyin/2, 
     zmin}, {xcenter + Dxin/2, ycenter + Dyin/2, 
     zmin}, {xcenter + Dxin/2, ycenter - Dyin/2, zmin}, {xcenter, 
     ycenter, zvertex}}];
cube = Cuboid[{xcenter - Dxin/2, ycenter - Dyin/2, 
    zmin}, {xcenter + Dxin/2, ycenter + Dyin/2, zmax}];
reg = RegionIntersection[pyramid, cube];
Region[reg]
```

[image]
I am wondering how it may be possible to define a region `reg2` with the same geometry as in the previous example but with `Dyout = 1` instead of `Dyout = 2`, i.e., the $y$ dimensions shrink faster than the $x$ dimensions.

**Edit**

This is my solution:

```
tempreg = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   xcenter - Dxz[z]/2 < x < xcenter + Dxz[z]/2 && 
    ycenter - Dyz[z]/2 < y < ycenter + Dyz[z]/2 && 
    zmin < z < zmax, {x, y, z}];
reg2 = RegionIntersection[cube, tempreg];
```

However, 1) it works very slowly since it deals with implicit regions, and 2) the region contains ugly meshes. I need a fast working and accurate solution since I will later use it to compute some geometric acceptances, etc.

To speed it up, I may discretize it:

```
reg2= DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[cube, tempreg], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> "Volume" -> 1];
Region[reg2]
```

[image]

But it is still ugly, and not accurate: say, `RegionMeasure` returns ~77.33 instead of 78.33 as it must be.

If decreasing `MaxCellMeasure`, I will, of course, improve the accuracy but slow down all the operations. Even the value 10^-3 does not give the very well accuracy, while slowing down everything significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat improving your code, the following works well for me.

```
Dxout = 1;xcenter = 5;Dyin = 6;Dyout = 1;ycenter = 0;zmin = 450;zmax = 460;
Dxz[z_] =  Dxin (zmax - z)/(zmax - zmin) + Dxout*(z - zmin)/(zmax - zmin);
Dyz[z_] =  Dyin (zmax - z)/(zmax - zmin) + Dyout*(z - zmin)/(zmax - zmin);
cube = Cuboid[{xcenter - Dxin/2, ycenter - Dyin/2, 
zmin}, {xcenter + Dxin/2, ycenter + Dyin/2, zmax}];
tempreg =  ImplicitRegion[Reduce[xcenter - Dxz[z]/2 < x < xcenter + Dxz[z]/2 && 
ycenter - Dyz[z]/2 < y < ycenter + Dyz[z]/2 && 
zmin < z < zmax] // Simplify, {x, y, z}];
inter = RegionIntersection[tempreg, cube];
Volume[inter] // Timing
```

> `{6.04688, 235/3}`

Addition.

```
RegionPlot3D[ RegionMember[inter, {x, y, z}], {x, 2, 8}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 445, 465},PlotPoints -> 50]
```

works slowly, but the result is not so bad:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, the graphical representation still looks like a piece of cake nibbled by a beaver.

Comment: @JohnTaylor: See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it may be possible to do this in the following way: we may define another pyramid with $dy(z)$ being `Dyz[z]` but $dx(z)$ corresponding to the $z$ dependence which vanishes at the same $z$ as `Dyz[z]`:

```
zvertex2 = z /. Solve[Dyz[z] == 0., z][[1]];
DxzFakeTemp[DxIn_, z_] = 
  DxIn*(zmax - z)/(zmax - zmin) + Dxout*(z - zmin)/(zmax - zmin);
DxInFake = DxIn /. Solve[DxzFakeTemp[DxIn, zvertex2] == 0, DxIn][[1]];
```

Then, the intersection of this region with `reg` as defined in my question would produce an accurate result:

```
pyramid2 = 
  Pyramid[{{xcenter - DxInFake/2, ycenter - Dyin/2, 
     zmin}, {xcenter - DxInFake/2, ycenter + Dyin/2, 
     zmin}, {xcenter + DxInFake/2, ycenter + Dyin/2, 
     zmin}, {xcenter + DxInFake/2, ycenter - Dyin/2, zmin}, {xcenter, 
     ycenter, zvertex2}}];
reg3 = RegionIntersection[pyramid2, reg];
```

Here, `reg3` is the desired region. I am still wondering, however, whether it may be possible to do this in a different way, possibly to generalize to more complicated geometries.